# Add <error-page> to specifc servlet within web.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets, error-handling

Currently my web.xml file includes two servlets:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-servlet</servlet-name>
...
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
...
</servlet>
```

If I just add "error-page" in the current web.xml it will handle the error for both "api" and "mvc-servlet", and I don't want this to happen. I want it to be applied ONLY to "mvc-servlet", not "api".

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch servlet exception and throw new exception(i.e ApiServletException), then you will be able to add error page only for this exception.